# Place a dividing line in a menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu

In XAML, how do I put a standard dividing line in a menu?

eg

```
<MenuItem Header="_File" Name="m_fileMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
    <!-- Trying to put a divider here! -->
    <MenuItem Header="-" />  <!-- Wrong guess -->
    <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use a `Separator` like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" />
<Separator />
<MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />
```

Comment: it seems like this is now called Divider not Separator?

Answer (score 6):

I needed to iterate through MenuItems for various reasons, and using Separator meant a bit of casting, so I used a 1px high MenuItem instead

```
<MenuItem Height="1" Background="LightGray"/>
```

The correct answer most definitely is to use Separator, but the above works visually too, and can be a solution in some cases.